# Can I use mutate filter in Logstash to convert some fields to integers of a genjdbc input?

Tags: jdbc, filter, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am using genjdbc input plugin for Logstash to get data from a DB2 database. It works perfectly, I get in Kibana all the database columns as fields.
The problem I have is that in Kibana all fields are string type, and I want the numeric fields to be integers. I have tried the following code, but the result is the same that if no filter clause exists.

Can someone help me solving this? Thanks in advance!

The logstash.conf code:

```
  input { 
    genjdbc {  
      jdbcHost       => "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
      jdbcPort       => "51260"
      jdbcTargetDB   => "db2"
      jdbcDBName     => "XXX"
      jdbcUser       => "XXX" 
      jdbcPassword   => "XXX"
      jdbcDriverPath => "C:\...\db2jcc4.jar"
      jdbcSQLQuery    => "SELECT * FROM XXX1"
      jdbcTimeField => "LOGSTAMP"
      jdbcPStoreFile => "C:\elk\logstash\bin\db2.pstore"
      jdbcURL => "jdbc:db2://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:51260/XXX"
      type => "table1"
    }
    genjdbc {  
      jdbcHost       => "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
      jdbcPort       => "51260"
      jdbcTargetDB   => "db2"
      jdbcDBName     => "XXX"
      jdbcUser       => "XXX" 
      jdbcPassword   => "XXX"
      jdbcDriverPath => "C:\...\db2jcc4.jar"
      jdbcSQLQuery    => "SELECT * FROM XXX2"
      jdbcTimeField => "LOGSTAMP"
      jdbcPStoreFile => "C:\elk\logstash\bin\db2.pstore"
      jdbcURL => "jdbc:db2://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:51260/XXX"
      type => "table2"
    }
  }

  filter {
    mutate {
      convert => [ "T1", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "T2", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "T3", "integer" ]
    }
  }

  output {
    if [type] == "table1" {
      elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost"
        protocol => "http"
        index => "db2_1-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      }
    }
    if [type] == "table2" {
      elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost"
        protocol => "http"
        index => "db2_2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have should work as long as the fields you are trying to convert to integer are names T1,T2,T3 and you are inserting into an index that doesn't have any data.  If you already have data in the index, you'll need to delete the index so that logstash can recreate it with the correct mapping.